# La instrucción foreach no puede funcionar en variables de tipo "Program"

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente problema con mi código **(Estoy realizando una Lista enlazada simple)**.

> Error  CS1579
>
> La instrucción `foreach` no puede funcionar en variables de tipo `Program` porque `Program` no contiene ninguna definición de instancia pública para `GetEnumerator`.

Trataba de hacer un `foreach` para comparar cual de los elementos era menor (y luego eliminarlo). Pero me da el error de que Lista es de tipo `Program`, no puedo hacer `foreach`.

Mi código:

```
    class Program
    {

        private Nodo primero;
        private int size;
        public Program() { 
            this.primero = null;
            this.size = 0;
        }

        public void AddNodo(int data) //Para el primer programa: Agregar los datos con su nodo
        {
            Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(data);// agregar nodo
            nuevo.next = primero; //para ir al primer nodo
            primero = nuevo; //coloca el elemento de primero
            size++;
        }

        public int Size() { //Para el primer programa, el size de la list
            return size;
        }
        public void listar() //Para el primer programa, para listar los elementos 
        {
            Nodo actual = primero;
            while (actual!=null)
            {
                Console.Write("[" + actual.data +"]->");
                actual = actual.next;

            }
        }
        public void DeleteList(int s) //para eleminar en una posicion especifica
        {
            Nodo anterior = primero;
            Nodo actual = primero;
            int dat = 0;
            if (s>0)
            {
                while (dat!= s && actual.next !=null)
                {
                    anterior = actual;
                    actual = actual.next;
                    dat++;
                }
                anterior.next = actual.next;
            }


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                case 1: //lista simplemente enlazada
                    Program Lista = new Program();
                    //Lista.ListaVacia();
                    Lista.AddNodo(5); //Para agregar el elemento; el ultimo elemento de la lista
                    Lista.AddNodo(85);
                    Lista.AddNodo(34);
                    Lista.AddNodo(56);
                    Lista.AddNodo(9);
                    Lista.AddNodo(12);// el primer elemento de la lista; cabeza o head


                    Lista.listar();
                    //Lista.DeleteList();
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Size " + Lista.Size()); //para el size

                    foreach (var item in Lista) //aqui es que me aparece el error
                    {

                    }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta el código de la clase `Nodo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder utilizar un ciclo `foreach` necesitas implementar la interfaz [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) ya que el ciclo *necesita* que la clase tenga un método [`GetEnumerator()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8) para invocarlo y así poder iterar sobre los elementos.

Como yo lo veo, y ya que estás haciendo una lista enlazada, te recomendaría algo así:

```
public IEnumerable<Nodo> Nodos
{
    List<Nodo> l = new List<Nodo>();
    Nodo actual = this.primero;
    do
    {
        l.Add(actual);
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    while (actual != null);
    return l;
}
```

Finalmente podrás iterar de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (var item in Lista.Nodos)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas usar un foreach ha de ser una clase que herede de ICollection (y alguna más), pero que este no es el caso, sólo tienes un objeto.

Aunque lo llames Lista, es como si lo hubieras declarado de tipo string, un string no puede ser usado en la parte derecha del IN del foreach.

Collection, Arrays, List.. Estos tipos si pueden ser usados en un foreach.
Si tienes alguna duda comentamelo y vemos si puedo ayudarte.

Un saludo!!

Comment: como puedo hacer que Lista sea un collection o un List? Por que lo intente convertir a List y no pude. Muchas gracias por su comentario!